# 404's in Wordpress when trying to access scripts

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this but I think this is a server / scrpting issue not specifically a Wordpress problem.  If you go to my site www.ThinkComputers.org and open firebug and Open the Net window you can see the 404 errors I am getting.

I can assure you those files are there, as I have doubled checked many times.

I think it has something to do with how those files are being called and possibly my permalink structure, which is /%postname%/

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be a rewrites problem. Can you post the WordPress relevant section of your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

I second Colin's hunch of an issue with the rewrites.  It is possible that either your .htaccess doesn't have the proper content or that your web server isn't allowing the use of mod_rewrite rules.

Check with your hosting company / server administrator that your virtual host has permission to use mod_wewrite and that the .htaccess looks something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the scripts and the directory can be read and executed by the webserver·
I'm assuming you're using a lamp system.

check if the permissions for the directory and scripts are set to r-x for everyone.